# NHibernate cascade delete

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, cascading-deletes

Let me begin with showing the mapping:

**Parent:**

```
<bag name="Communicatiekanalen" table="COMMUNICATIEKANAAL" inverse="true" cascade="delete" lazy="true" >
        <key column="SEK_PROFIEL"/>
        <one-to-many class="Crm.Hibernate.Communicatiekanaal,Crm.Hibernate" />
</bag>
```

**Child:**

```
<many-to-one name="SekProfiel" column="SEK_PROFIEL" class="Crm.Hibernate.Profiel,Crm.Hibernate" />
```

In other words: a profile can have many communication channels.

On the UI (user-interface *[ASP.NET Webforms]*) the following event is fired
(deleting a profile with communication channels attached to it) :

```
    var profielDao = CrmConfiguration.GetDaoFactory().GetProfielDao();
    var profiel = profielDao.GetById(2194, true); //lets say '2194' is an ID that exists
    profielDao.Delete(profiel);
```

(the DaoFactory is located in one project file and the UI is an ASP.NET Website)

This code works.

**IMPORTANT:** the code is using the NHibernate 'open-session-in-view' pattern.

I have a service implementation that fires the same code (deleting a profile with communication channels). Some code...

```
            var daof = CrmConfiguration.GetDaoFactory();
            CrmSettings.Instance.UserID = user;
            var profielDao = daof.GetProfielDao();

            profielDao.BeginTransaction();
            var profiel = profielDao.GetById(CrmEntitiesToHibernate.ParseStringToId(profileId), true);
            profielDao.Delete(profiel);
            profielDao.EndTransaction();
```

Where 'EndTransaction()' does a 'commit'. I test this code with an 'unit test':

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDeleteProfile()
    {
        //Getting a valid NEW profile
        var profile = GetSecundaryProfile();
        //Adding a communication channel to the profile
        CrmClient.AddCommunicationChannelForProfile(GetPlainCommunicationChannel(), profile.Id, CurrentUserId);
        //Calling the 'delete profile' method on the service --> FAIL - no cascade
        CrmClient.DeleteProfile(profile.Id, CurrentUserId);
    }
```

This code fails. The following error is bugging me:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with
>   the REFERENCE constraint "R2_PROFIEL".
>   The conflict occurred in database
>   "CRM_ontw", table
>   "dbo.COMMUNICATIEKANAAL", column
>   'SEK_PROFIEL'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

This means that the cascade didn't happen at all. Executed from the **UI** it **works**, but when fired from the '**service implementation**', it **fails**. Any ideas or suggestions that could help me?

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit:** the following generic code delete's an object

```
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            OnDelete(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            SessionManager.Instance.RollbackTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath);
            throw;
        }
        session.Delete(entity);
    }
```

Setting the `all-delete-orphan` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What's the implementation of `profielDao.Delete(profiel)`?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem. The NHibernate 'open-session-in-view' pattern closes the session after commiting the changes to the database (so when the requests ends, the sessions gets closed):

```
        finally
        {
            // No matter what happens, make sure all the sessions get closed
            foreach (SessionFactoryElement sessionFactorySettings in openSessionInViewSection.SessionFactories)
            {
                SessionManager.Instance.CloseSessionOn(sessionFactorySettings.FactoryConfigPath);
            }
        }
```

But my `EndTransaction()` implementation on the service side didn't.

So with a few tweaks I created this `EndTransaction()` method:

```
public void EndTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        SessionManager.Instance.CommitTransactionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath);
    }
    finally
    {
        SessionManager.Instance.CloseSessionOn(SessionFactoryConfigPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `cascade="delete"` to `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`

Also, ensure that in both instances, the parent is being **read** and **saved** by the same `ISession` instance. As someone commented, we need to see the implementation of your `.Delete()` method.

Comment: Or apply DELETE CASCADE option to a FK